# Android Studio cannot use secure connection for update, complaining the use of Java 6

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8, java-7, java-6

In Android Studio's `Preferences` -> `Appearance & Behavior` -> `System Settings` -> `Updates`, I tried to enable the `Use secure connection` option:

[image]

But when I clicked the `Apply` button, the error `"Secure connection is not supported on Java 6"` showed up:

[image]

I checked the JDK location setting in `Project Structure`, and it's `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home`:

[image]

It seems that I'm using Java 7, not Java 6.  Then why the secure connection setting complains about not supported by Java 6?

---

In case needed, below is the installed JDKs on my machine:
[image]

The first one `1.6.0.jdk` is from [Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US), and the other 3 are from Oracle.

Comment: What JVM version does it report when you select "Android Studio -> About Android Studio" from the top-level menu?

Comment: @DougStevenson Ah, it shows `1.6.0_65xxxxxx` there.  So it's the version of `jre` that Android Studio uses causes the problem, not the `jdk` version?  How to change the `jre` version to be used by Android Studio?

Comment: I have always found that it uses the most recent version that I installed.  I'm surprised that this is not the case for you.  But I also have this in my .bash_profile: export JAVA_HOME=\`/usr/libexec/java_home\`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem occurs on Mac OS.
The project JDK (the JDK used for compiling your code) is different from the IDE JDK (the JDK used to run the IDE)

Your project JDK is 7, but your IDE JDK is 6.

For your case, you can add an environment variable for the IDE (by Terminal) as below:

```
export STUDIO_JDK=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk
```

Check these documents for more information:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Exporting environment variable didn't work for me. Editing plist file did.

```
nano /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

And find this line:

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.6*</string>
```

Change the value from 1.6* to 1.7+

Answer (score -1):

Its seems to be a bug that has already been documented by project members ([link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176183)). This bug has been there for quite sometime it seems. The screenshot attached in the thread in which this issue is being discussed is definitely of an older version than Android Studio 2.0

At this stage I'm unable to find anything related to changing JRE for Android Studio or Intellij. You can change the JDK, but that has no effect on this error warning.

Will update this thread as more information becomes available on tackling this issue.